# Overwrite synthetic events from a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a UI library I have a Checkbox class, which allows the user to add a input[type=checkbox] to a form, styles it and adds extra functionality:

```
export class Checkbox extends React.Component({
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="form-component">
        <input type="checkbox" 
          defaultChecked={this.props.value} 
          checked={this.props.value}
          name={this.props.name} />
        <label>{this.props.label}</label>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

The change handler is done at the form level.

```
export class Page extends React.Component({
  handleChange(event) {
    let state = {};
    state[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(state);
  }
  render() {
    <form onChange={this.handleChange}>
      <Input value={this.state.value} name="input1" />
      <Checkbox value={this.state.value} name="checkbox1" />
    </form>
  }
})
```

The synthetic change event from the input returns an event object with `event.target.name` and `event.target.value`. The checkbox has `event.target.checked` instead. In the handle change event I can see what type of element it is choose accordingly.

But is there a way for me to overwrite the event being emitted from the Checkbox component, so that `event.target.value === event.target.checked`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the value of `CheckBox` on it's `onChange` event. Because the event in `CheckBox` will be called before the `onChange` event, so you can format `e.target` to return what you want. Try this:

```
var CheckBox = React.createClass({
handleChange: function(e){
e.target.value = e.target.checked
},
render: function(){
    return (
    <div className="form-component">
    <input type="checkbox" 
      defaultChecked={this.props.value} 
      checked={this.props.value}
      name={this.props.name}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    <label>{this.props.label}</label>
     </div>
  )
  }
 });
```

But be careful, e.target.value just changes into a String `"false"` and `"true"`, not `Boolean`